# AlertPrompt getting smashed by CLLocation prompt

Tags: ios, uialertview, cllocation

On my app's first launch, an AlertPrompt comes up asking for an email address. This happens right before CLLocation's built-in alert comes up, obliterating my email prompt. As soon as I select "OK" (allow app to use your current location), my email prompt comes back. I'm using this for the email prompt:

```
- (void)askEmailReal {
    AlertPrompt *prompt = [AlertPrompt alloc];
    prompt = [prompt initWithTitle:nil 
                           message:text
                          delegate:nil
                 cancelButtonTitle:@"No thanks" 
                     okButtonTitle:@"Submit"];
    [prompt show];
```

Not sure how best to proceed. Is it possible to block the system's location prompt until mine is clicked? Or maybe I should make sure mine comes after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to block the system prompts. If you really want your email pop up to show before the System's current location prompt, then simply just allocate your `CLLocationManager` and call your initial `startUpdatingLocation` after you've received the alertview callback that the user entered their email credentials.